# Install bower component (angular-qr-scanner) using Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, bower

I'm trying to install [Angular QR Scanner](https://github.com/sembrestels/angular-qr-scanner) in my Meteor app. It seems the only way to install it is using Bower, however [bower support for Meteor seems to be deprecated now for 1.3](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-bower). I tried installing using `npm install` however I receive an error that `qrcode.decode is not a function`, despite importing both files needed.

Is there another way to install bower components using Meteor?

Comment: Sometimes a package should be imported using require('module-name') as it may not  export the variables for you to use import

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just importing the plain javascript implementation with [html5-qrcode](https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode) rather than using an angular directive.